# Return the AVG of the Top 5 Values in Query Results

Tags: sql, oracle

**Question:** How would I return the AVG of the Top 5 values in the Payment Ranking query below.

**Database**: Oracle 11g

**Current Query**

```
select distinct pye.payeeid, pay.value,
dense_rank() over (partition by bu.name order by pay.value DESC) as "Payment Ranking"

from cs_period per, cs_payee pye, cs_payment pay, cs_businessunit bu

where per.name = 'August 2014'
and pye.payeeseq = pay.payeeseq
and pay.businessunitmap = bu.mask
and pye.effectiveenddate = to_date('01/01/2200','dd/mm/yyyy')
and pye.removedate = to_date('01/01/2200','dd/mm/yyyy')
and per.periodseq = pay.periodseq
order by pay.value DESC
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Quick question - do you want the top 5 in terms of `RANK()` or in terms of `DENSE_RANK()`? The reason I ask is that there can be more than 5 rows with a `DENSE_RANK()` of 5 or lower, so if you want the top 5 calculated according to your "Payment Ranking" then a solution based on ROWNUM won't work.

Comment: I need the AVG of the top 5 regardless of uniqueness. For example, assume a top 7 of {500, 400, 400, 300, 200, 200, 100}, I would calculate the top 5 AVG for 500, 400, 400, 300, 200. Is this the correct use of DENSE_RANK? Thanks!

Comment: OK then you want the solution which uses `ROWNUM` instead of the calculated value of `DENSE_RANK()`. Whether `DENSE_RANK()` is appropriate in this situation is really up to your business requirements!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the top 5 according to "Payment Ranking" (for which you used `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `RANK()` or `ROW_NUMBER()`):

```
SELECT AVG(value) FROM (
    select distinct pye.payeeid, pay.value
         , dense_rank() over (partition by bu.name order by pay.value DESC) as payment_ranking
     from cs_period per, cs_payee pye, cs_payment pay, cs_businessunit bu
    where per.name = 'August 2014'
      and pye.payeeseq = pay.payeeseq
      and pay.businessunitmap = bu.mask
      and pye.effectiveenddate = to_date('01/01/2200','dd/mm/yyyy')
      and pye.removedate = to_date('01/01/2200','dd/mm/yyyy')
      and per.periodseq = pay.periodseq
) WHERE payment_ranking <= 5
```

Note that all I did was take your query and use it as a subquery, adding a `WHERE` clause to restrict to the top 5 ranked payments.

Answer (score 3):

```
select avg(payment)
from
(
    <your query here>
)
where rownum <= 5
```

Assumed you keep the ordering as shown in your query.